# How do I find the width/height of ImageView?

Tags: android, image, height, width

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680499/android-get-height-width-of-imageview). I've used [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images) to extend ImageView to form TouchImageView. In my onCreate() method, I want to call

```
setImage(Bitmap bm, int displayWidth, int displayHeight)
```

but I don't know the width or height to use. When I call getHeight(), it gives me zero.

I tried to avoid the 0 using [kcoppock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/321697/kcoppock)'s answer to the [previously mentioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680499/android-get-height-width-of-imageview), but was unsuccessful. The onPreDraw() listener is called several times per second and I can't figure out how to only call it once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a brittle approach for something like this. Android Views are measured by their parent View using the `onMeasure` method. By providing an initial size to a `setImage` method to scale to (and especially if you set it based on the display size) you're inviting complexity whenever you want to nest this View within others. Larger screen devices like tablets are a good example of this.

A more idiomatic approach would implement the `setImage` method of TouchImageView without the width/height parameters at all. Instead it would defer setting the scale and matrices until measurement and implement `onMeasure` something like this:

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    if (mNeedsInitialScale) { // Set by setImage when a new image is set
        // The measured width and height were set by super.onMeasure above
        setInitialScale(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
        mNeedsInitialScale = false;
    }
}
```

Where the `setInitialScale` method does everything that the linked `setImage` method does after the call to `super.setImageBitmap`. `setImage` should also set the `mNeedsInitialScale` field to `true`.

This way you will never need to worry about the initial size to use, it will be obtained automatically from the View during normal measurement whenever a new image is set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That solved my problem and my code is much better now.

Comment: Actually, it looked like it was working well, but `getMeasuredWidth()` and `getMeasuredHeight()` seem to be returning the width and height of the parent view.

Comment: It turns out that `onMeasure(int int)` gets called several times to measure the `ImageView`. I expect it gets called whenever a sibling is added. I moved `mNeedsInitialScale = false;` to the beginning of my `setScale(float)` method and now it works fine.

Comment: Yes, onMeasure will be called whenever a View is asked to measure with different MeasureSpecs than it used last time. This can happen whenever a layout is requested. Glad it worked out. :)

Answer (score 1):

the ImageViews dimensions are 0 until your Activity draw it on the screen. You could use Activitys onFocusChanged to set the Bitmap and get correct Dimensions
if you are just looking for DisplayWidth and height you can call

```
Display d = getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE).getDefaultDisplay();
```

and ask Display for its dimensions