# Square layout not working in landscape

Tags: android, view, android-custom-view, custom-view

Why is my square view not working in landscape mode?

It has following `onMeasure` method:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    size = Math.min(width, height);
    setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
}
```

Here you see the background of my view (in gray) and that my view is not square. Why?

[image]

And here's my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/md_dialog_frame_margin">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <com.my.package.GridPreviewView
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:background="#cccccc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/npCols"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/npRows" />

        <com.shawnlin.numberpicker.NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/npRows"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/grid"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            app:np_dividerColor="?attr/colorAccent"
            app:np_orientation="vertical"
            app:np_selectedTextColor="?attr/colorAccent"
            app:np_selectedTextSize="22sp"
            app:np_textSize="18sp"
            app:np_width="48dp" />

        <com.shawnlin.numberpicker.NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/npCols"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/grid"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            app:np_dividerColor="?attr/colorAccent"
            app:np_height="48dp"
            app:np_orientation="horizontal"
            app:np_selectedTextColor="?attr/colorAccent"
            app:np_selectedTextSize="22sp"
            app:np_textSize="18sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Related or duplicate? [Why is my android custom view not square?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228741/why-is-my-android-custom-view-not-square) - btw I only get a square View in portrait if I leave out the `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Am not exactly sure what the problem may be with the `onMeasure()` technique you are using, but check out [SquareLayout](https://github.com/kaushikthedeveloper/SquareLayout), an **Android Library** which provides a wrapper class for different Layouts, rendering them Squared dimensioned without losing any core functionalities.

The dimensions are calculated just before the Layout is rendered, hence there is no re-rendering or anything as such to adjust once the View is obtained. This will work in every and all scenarios (including **view orientation change**)

To use the Library, add this to your build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.kaushikthedeveloper:squarelayout:0.0.3'
}
```

Note : The XML preview may be broken for the moment, but it works perfectly fine when running the app.