# In SurfaceView's onMeasure(), how can I calculate the size of current view

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In my android video player, how can I set the size of video, so that it can fit in the view.

I've created a `CustomView extends SurfaceView`. in the overriden `onMeasure()`, I'm thinking of calculating the size of my CustomView (which displays the video).

Then pass those dimensions in  `setMeasuredDimension(width, height);`.

I've not come across any other method to set the dimensions of video manually.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perfect example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266899/onmeasure-custom-view-explanation?rq=1), or look at this,

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

int desiredWidth = 100;
int desiredHeight = 100;

int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

int width;
int height;

//Measure Width
if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
    //Must be this size
    width = widthSize;
} else if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
    //Can't be bigger than...
    width = Math.min(desiredWidth, widthSize);
} else {
    //Be whatever you want
    width = desiredWidth;
}

//Measure Height
if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
    //Must be this size
    height = heightSize;
} else if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
    //Can't be bigger than...
    height = Math.min(desiredHeight, heightSize);
} else {
    //Be whatever you want
    height = desiredHeight;
}

//MUST CALL THIS
setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
```

Hope its help.