# Custom view onMeasure

Tags: android, android-view

I have a custom view (extending `RelativeLayout`) enable to display a text or/and an icon.

The problem is when I set `wrap_content` for `width` attribute, the view takes the whole size available and I want that my view takes only the place needed by the text or/and icon (of course when I set `wrap_content`).

I think I have to override the `onMeasure()` method but I don't really understand how do it works.

I have a look to the default `TextView` `onMeasure()` method but it is really huge !

Comment: [This answer should work for you.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266899/onmeasure-custom-view-explanation

Comment: Yes I've already seen this post, but for wrap_content mode, it doesn't work...