# How to call onMeasure when changing layout width and height

Tags: android, android-canvas, onmeasure

Hi I am working on canvas drawing. For that I am using custom view `Activity`(extends `View`) this view added into `ScrollView` in mainactivity(extends `Activity`) for scrolling canvas and my custom view width and height 700*3000 and at runtime custom view width and height increased.

Now how I can call `onMeasure()` when changing width and height.

This `onMeasure()` called when custom view calls. But at runtime it's not called until unless `onResume()` calls.

For calling `onMeasure()`, I am using `measure(width,heigt);` in `onTouch()`.

But it's not called.Is it possible to call `onMeasure()` at runtime. Then,How?
Any one give me a solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266899/onmeasure-custom-view-explanation

Comment: try calling requestLayout

Comment: requestLayout() is working.