# Android TableLayout contains custom view only displays first row

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-tablelayout

I want to add custom view to a TableLayout with following code:

My custom view class:

```
public class MyCustomView extends View{
...
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       super.onDraw(canvas);
      //draw on canvas      
   }
}
```

Added the view to table layout in another class:

```
public class MyTableView extends TableLayout{
....
private void AddViews(int column,int row){
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        TableRow tableRows = new TableRow(mContext);
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            MyCustomView myView= new MyCustomView();
            tableRows.addView(dayView);
        }
        addView(tableRows); 
    }

}
```

}

The table only displays first row:

| MyCustomView | MyCustomView | MyCustomView |

But if I change MyCustomView to inherit from TextView:

```
public class MyCustomView extends TextView
```

The table correctly displays all rows:

| MyCustomView | MyCustomView | MyCustomView |

| MyCustomView | MyCustomView | MyCustomView |

| MyCustomView | MyCustomView | MyCustomView |

What does the TextView have but the View doesn't which is causing the difference in TableLayout?

Should I add something to my custom view?

Note: I tried to set layout TableLayout.ParamLayout as LayoutParamater of the view, it doesn't work either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I need to override `onMeasure()` in my custom view if I want to use `WRAP_CONTENT` for the custom view's layout param so that the parent layout which is the TableLayout can correctly recognize the height of the custom view and then display it correctly.

[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12267248/1549865)  has great explanation for this.

Or by specifying the height of the custom view using layout param instead of using `WRAP_CONTENT` works also.