# Android Canvas generate Arc without extra space

Tags: android, canvas, android-custom-view

I am using canvas to create a custom view. This view generates a shape like piece of pizza.This has been done using drawArc method of Canvas. This is working good. But upon generation , the view takes up a rectangular conatiner instead of shape of that view. I want to clip that extra part. How can this be achieved?

Comment: override `onMeasure` then

Comment: I am new to custom Layout creation and failed to understand true purpose of onMeasure. Can you elaborate @pskink

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12267248/2252830