# Customized View with Horizontal Scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-scrolling

I am trying to write a custom View with the ability of scroll horizontally. I have gone through many posts on the forums but I am still unable to get what I want.
I want a custom view on which I am plotting the pitch contour of an audio recording. The pitch contour is quite long to fit in the screen. So, I want to add a horizontal scroll to this.
As of now, I have created a customized view extending `HorizontalScrollView`. Once the window has the focus, I `invalidate()` the view and draw the pitch contour on the screen. After I complete drawing, I try to jump to the right most position by calling `scrollTo(getRight(), 0)`. This doesn't change anything and the contour is exactly the same position. When I try to print the value using `getRight()`, it gives me the value `1794`. I am using a Nexux 5 for testing. Can anyone give me any hints on this?

PS: The x pixel value for the last value in the contour is `Last value of x for is:5499.3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake I was doing was not to provide an implementation for `onMeasure()` inside my custom `View`. If the custom view has the `layout_width` mentioned as `wrap_content` (in case of a `HorizontalScrollView`), we need to set the width of the custom view inside `onMeasure()`. A good explanation of the same is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266899/onmeasure-custom-view-explanation). Hope this is helpful to other people.