# Android view dynamic size

Tags: java, android

I have a layout with several views and one of these views have to be scaled based on screen size. As of now I have it set to 250dp as it looks good on a 5.1 inch device, but when used on smaller devices it isnt as good any more. I can't use wrap content as it will make the looks of it very bad and the size of buttons too small, so it has to be 1/3rd of the width of the screen. Is it possible to do that in the layout code, or does it have to be doen in java code?

Comment: from the links you gave...
The actual measurement work of a view is performed in onMeasure(int, int), called by this method. Therefore, only onMeasure(int, int) can and must be overridden by subclasses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do that in the layout code

Yes it is. It is pretty simple by using `android:layout_weight` and `android:weightSum` attributes of `LinearLayout` :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent" 
   android:weightSum="3"
   android:orientation="horizontal"> 

   <View 
      android:id="@+id/thirdView" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_width="0dp" 
      android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I like weights but heavy loading there...:D

Answer (score 0):

You need to override onMeasure(...) then do your view resizing login inside this function. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266899/onmeasure-custom-view-explanation) is the perfect explanation and solution.
Some reference code from this link goes below...

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    int desiredWidth = 100;
    int desiredHeight = 100;

    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    int width;
    int height;

    //Measure Width
    if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        //Must be this size
        width = widthSize;
    } else if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        //Can't be bigger than...
        width = Math.min(desiredWidth, widthSize);
    } else {
        //Be whatever you want
        width = desiredWidth;
    }

    //Measure Height
    if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        //Must be this size
        height = heightSize;
    } else if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        //Can't be bigger than...
        height = Math.min(desiredHeight, heightSize);
    } else {
        //Be whatever you want
        height = desiredHeight;
    }

    //MUST CALL THIS
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
```

Comment: isnt that for the entire layout itself? i want to rezise a single view not the layout

Comment: You view must be sitting inside a container?

Comment: the layouts are made in .xml files. The base in a layout file layout of one of many types(e.g. FrameLayout, RelativeLayout and LinearLayout). is that counted as a container?

Comment: Who will add code snippets then?

Comment: what do you mean? i dont understand hints m8

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the [`PercentRelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) from the [Percent Support Library](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/support-library/features.html#percent). This is a `RelativeLayout` in which you can specify it's Views sizes in percentages, e.g. set its width to 33%.

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <Button
         app:layout_widthPercent="33%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="33%"
         app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
         app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%" />

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i keep getting an exception that basicly is that it doesnt find the values in my game's package

Comment: @TheRealPolarbear What's the exact error message? Did you include the library correctly?

Comment: did i have to add a .jar? that explains the error

Comment: ok it wasnt as easy as that i see. im using eclipse, so do i have to make a build.gradle file and add it to whatever so it is imported like that or can i just add it to the java build path?

Comment: @TheRealPolarbear Would be easy with Android Studio.. For Eclipse you can try to include the library located at [android-sdk]/extras/android/compatibility/percent/

Comment: that isnt a valid path. ill see if i have all the extras installed though

Comment: found it at [android-sdk]/extras/android/percent/ but i tried @AleksandrMedvedev 's weight system and it worked