# what's the difference between view and viewgroup for the method onMeasure()?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, viewgroup, onmeasure

I am learning a custom component, and I find some difference in the `view` and `viewgroup` for the method `onMeasure()`.For example, someone calls `super.onMeasure`, someone uses `setMeasuredDimension` at the end. Where is a difference? And `measureChildren()` means what?

This is the first time I've come this community, hope get the answer I wanted, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> super.onMeasure()

This is used when you want to leave the measuring of your custom component to the super class you are extending from. For example, lets say you are building a custom TextView for multi colored texts. You really don't want to override the `onMeasure()` implementation of TextView because you are not dealing with the width and height of the text. So you can call `super.onMeasure()` and leave the measuring to `TextView`.

> setMeasuredDimension()

In case, you do have to override `onMeasure()`, you use `setMeasuredDimension()` to tell the android view rendering system the final calculated width and height of your custom view. This will be used by the view system for rendering your view.

> measureChildren()
>   It tells the children of this `ViewGroup` to measure themselves using the given`MeasureSpec`.

A very nice discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266899/onmeasure-custom-view-explanation).