# How to get Custom ViewGroup height in onMeasure

Tags: android, android-custom-view, onmeasure

This is `onMeasure()` on CustomView which `extend FrameLayout`. After investigate `onMeasure()`, heigh size is always zero. How could I know what is the height size of this CustomView to manipulate child view later.

```
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

            int viewHeightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
            int viewWidthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
            int viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            int viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all please read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266899/onmeasure-custom-view-explanation). It is about measuring of `View`.

Main difference about `ViewGroup` that you should measure in your code all your childs.

```
for(int i=0; i<getChildCount(); i++) {
    View child = getChildAt(i);
    LayoutParams lp = child.getLayoutParams();
    int widthMeasureMode = lp.width == LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ? MeasureSpec.AT_MOST : MeasureSpec.EXACTLY,
        heightMeasureMode = lp.height == LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ? MeasureSpec.AT_MOST : MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
    int widthMeasure = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth() - left, widthMeasureMode),
        heightMeasure = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getHeight() - top, heightMeasureMode);
    child.measure(widthMeasure, heightMeasure);
    int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth(),
        childHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();
    //make something with that
}
```

That shows how to get size of all childs. May be you want to calculate sum of heights, may be just find maximum value - it is your own goal.

By the way. If your base class is not `ViewGroup`, but `FrameLayout` for example, measuring childs could be done in `onLayout` method. In this case in your `onMeasure` method you can do nothing about measuring childs - just take sizes. **But it is just a guess - better to check that.**

Comment: Thank for info, I'll try base on your info