# Xamarin Android "ScrollView" strange behavior

Tags: android, xamarin, textview, scrollview

I created custom "TextView" that text lines are drawn in the overridden OnDraw method by canvas.DrawText method. Everything was fine until I added ScrollView:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollV"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <myapp.TextViewJustifiable
        android:id="@+id/textViewJustifiableAlertMessage"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#333333" />
  </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

In general, ScrollView does not show nth text line of the custom TextView! For example, if TextView has 20 lines of text, only 19 lines are scrolled and line of 20 is not shown at all! When I delete OnDraw method everything is OK.

Where do you think the problem is?

Comment: Have you overrided the [onMeasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266899/onmeasure-custom-view-explanation) method?

Comment: @Joe Lv - MSFT No I have not.

Comment: If you use `wrap_content`  in your custom view, you need override it.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I used SetHeight method in the end of overridden OnDraw method.

Comment: Could you please show your `TextViewJustifiable`? If you  use `wrap_content`, and not override `onMeasure` method, the system don't know the specific size. And why do you use `SetHeight`?  You need use `setMeasuredDimension` to define the width and height.

Comment: I use wrap_content for height of TextViewJustifiable. Using overridden onMeasure method causes to disappear of TextViewJustifiable contents! I use SetHeight in OnDraw method to set actual height of control after text lines drawn to screen. It works fine.

Comment: Good luck, could you please post an answer for your question? So it will help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used SetHeight method in the end of the overridden OnDraw method to solve the issue:

```
> protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
>         {
>             float floatCharSpaceSize;
>             float floatWordWidth;
>             float floatEmptySpace;
>             float floatJustifedSpaceSize;
>             float floatLineWidth;
>             float floatTextAreaWidth;
>             float floatWordPositionX;
>             float floatWordPositionY;
>             int intLineEnd;
>             int intLineStart;
>             int intSpaceCount;
>             int intTextHeight;
>             int intRemaindedSpaceSize;
>             Layout layoutTextView;
>             Paint.FontMetrics fontMetrics_Paint;
>             string stringLine;
>             string stringText;
>             string[] stringArrWord;
>             TextPaint textPaint = Paint;
> 
>             textPaint.Color = new Color(CurrentTextColor);
>             textPaint.DrawableState = GetDrawableState();
>             floatTextAreaWidth = MeasuredWidth - (PaddingLeft + PaddingRight);
>             floatCharSpaceSize = textPaint.MeasureText(" ");
>             stringText = Text;
>             floatWordPositionY = TextSize + PaddingTop;
>             layoutTextView = Layout;
> 
>             if (layoutTextView == null)
>             {
>                 return;
>             }
> 
>             fontMetrics_Paint = textPaint.GetFontMetrics();
>             intTextHeight = (int)(Math.Ceiling(fontMetrics_Paint.Bottom - fontMetrics_Paint.Top) *
> LineSpacingMultiplier + layoutTextView.SpacingAdd);
> 
>             for (int intIndexA = 0; intIndexA < layoutTextView.LineCount; intIndexA++)
>             {
>                 intLineStart = layoutTextView.GetLineStart(intIndexA);
>                 intLineEnd = layoutTextView.GetLineEnd(intIndexA);
>                 floatLineWidth = StaticLayout.GetDesiredWidth(Text, intLineStart, intLineEnd, textPaint);
>                 stringLine = Text.Substring(intLineStart, intLineEnd - intLineStart);
> 
>                 if (stringLine[stringLine.Length - 1] == ' ')
>                 {
>                     stringLine = stringLine.Substring(0, stringLine.Length - 1);
>                     floatLineWidth -= floatCharSpaceSize;
>                 }
> 
>                 if (BoolJustify == true && intIndexA < layoutTextView.LineCount - 1)
>                 {
>                     floatEmptySpace = floatTextAreaWidth - floatLineWidth;
>                     intSpaceCount = stringLine.Split(' ').Length - 1;
>                     floatJustifedSpaceSize = (int)(floatEmptySpace / intSpaceCount) + floatCharSpaceSize;
>                     intRemaindedSpaceSize = (int)(((floatEmptySpace / intSpaceCount) - (int)(floatEmptySpace / intSpaceCount)) *
> intSpaceCount);
>                     stringArrWord = stringLine.Split(new char[1] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
> 
>                     if (IntLangDirection == (int)ApplicationLSchool.LangDirection.LTR)
>                     {
>                         floatWordPositionX = 0;
> 
>                         for (int intIndexB = 0; intIndexB < stringArrWord.Length; intIndexB++)
>                         {
>                             floatWordWidth = StaticLayout.GetDesiredWidth(stringArrWord[intIndexB], textPaint);
> 
>                             canvas.DrawText(stringArrWord[intIndexB], floatWordPositionX, floatWordPositionY, textPaint);
> 
>                             if (intRemaindedSpaceSize > 0)
>                             {
>                                 floatWordPositionX += floatWordWidth + floatJustifedSpaceSize + 1;
> 
>                                 intRemaindedSpaceSize--;
>                             }
>                             else
>                             {
>                                 floatWordPositionX += floatWordWidth + floatJustifedSpaceSize;
>                             }
>                         }
>                     }
>                     else if (IntLangDirection == (int)ApplicationLSchool.LangDirection.RTL)
>                     {
>                         floatWordPositionX = floatTextAreaWidth;
> 
>                         for (int intIndexB = 0; intIndexB < stringArrWord.Length; intIndexB++)
>                         {
>                             floatWordWidth = StaticLayout.GetDesiredWidth(stringArrWord[intIndexB], textPaint);
> 
>                             canvas.DrawText(stringArrWord[intIndexB], floatWordPositionX - floatWordWidth, floatWordPositionY, textPaint);
> 
>                             if (intRemaindedSpaceSize > 0)
>                             {
>                                 floatWordPositionX -= floatWordWidth + floatJustifedSpaceSize + 1;
> 
>                                 intRemaindedSpaceSize--;
>                             }
>                             else
>                             {
>                                 floatWordPositionX -= floatWordWidth + floatJustifedSpaceSize;
>                             }
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     if (IntLangDirection == (int)ApplicationLSchool.LangDirection.LTR)
>                     {
>                         canvas.DrawText(stringLine, 0, floatWordPositionY, textPaint);
>                     }
>                     else if (IntLangDirection == (int)ApplicationLSchool.LangDirection.RTL)
>                     {
>                         canvas.DrawText(stringLine, floatTextAreaWidth - floatLineWidth, floatWordPositionY, textPaint);
>                     }
>                 }
> 
>                 floatWordPositionY += intTextHeight;
>             }
> 
>             **SetHeight((int)(floatWordPositionY - TextSize - layoutTextView.SpacingAdd) + PaddingBottom);**
>         }
```