# How to set custom view height half of width Inside itself?

Tags: android, height, width, android-linearlayout

android how to set custom **`LinearLayout`** height half of width Inside herself.

```
 @Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec / 2);
}
```

i use this code but child's are cut off.

Comment: `widthMeasureSpec` is not what you think. It is not the width.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266899/onmeasure-custom-view-explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CustomLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

    private static final float RATIO = 0.5f;

    public CustomLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        int customHeight = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                            (int)(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec) * RATIO), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        super.onMeasure(widthSpec, customHeight);
    }
}
```