# Android resize imageview programmatically

Tags: android

Is it possible to resize an imageview in code? I tried:

```
img.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
```

but the app crashes if I do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set ImageView width and height programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144940/set-imageview-width-and-height-programmatically). please add your stacktrace here.  If you're setting the width after the layout has already been 'laid out', then make sure you also add `img.requestLayout()`.

Comment: Stacktrace: http://textuploader.com/d0gvw  The img.requestLayout(); is not working....

Comment: your `img` is null.Show the `img` in xml if you've defined it there .and show how you get the view of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app may be crashing because your ImageView may not have been dynamically generated (your stack trace link is a 404 so I can't verify).

In any case, to make the system redraw your ImageView you must call `img.requestLayout()`. However, calling `requestLayout()` [is not guaranteed to result in an onDraw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35279374/why-is-requestlayout-being-called-directly-after-invalidate/42430021#42430021) contrary to documentation, so in practice `invalidate()` is also called following the `requestLayout()`

Try this:

```
img.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
img.requestLayout();
img.invalidate();
```

**EDIT:**

The stack trace is now available. Looks like you're getting a NullPointerException when you try setting the ImageView's width. Are you sure your ImageView has been declared? If it has been declared then have you added it to your layout? An ImageView not added to the layout will return null when trying to access it's LayoutParams (because it's not a part of the layout yet)

Comment: Sorry for the 404, your method is not working. This is a valid page:https://hastebin.com/ayakumuwiz.sql

Comment: Thanks! it is fixed

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new. How can i do that?

Comment: @NilsPMC there's a tick mark next to my answer. If you click it, the tick mark turns green, and the answer is marked as correct.