# Cannot getHeight of TextView when Fragment onCreateView

Tags: android, fragment

I have a Fragment which contain a TextView call as mTextView. I want to get height of mTextView after append content to it in onCreateView of Fragment like this:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.myfragment, container, false);

        mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
               int mHeight=mTextView.getHeight();

 }
```

but it's always return 0 value.

Comment: Give it a try using the below link, http://adanware.blogspot.in/2012/06/android-getting-measuring-fragment.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to get it after

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
```

right?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to get the height just after onCreate, you won't be able to get because still the window is not focused. Try like this :

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // your code here
    int mHeight=mTextView.getHeight();
}
```

Comment: I don't see the method onWindowFocusChanged in my fragment class :(

Comment: oh then you need to use message handler to get the correct height. Set a message handler inside your fragment class at a delay of 1 sec once handler fired try inside handler to get the height. If you still not able to get let me know..

Comment: I think so but I think it's not a good solution to resolve this problem :(

Comment: yea but for getting height at least view should be focused on the screen and it takes some time, you just can't call the next line of set view to get the height.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the View's dimentions are 0 is because when you are querying them, the view still haven't performed the layout and measure steps. You only told the view how it would "behave" in the layout, but it still didn't calculated where to put each view.

There are a few tricks to get that size though. You can use this question as a starting point although I don't like the accepted answer's approach very much.

[How to get the width and height of an android.widget.ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680499/android-get-height-width-of-imageview/)