# how to get the width and height of any given imageView?

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, bitmapimage, bitmapfactory

I am trying to scale and rotate an image. And as the method `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()` demands to specify the desired width and height, I want to set the desired width and the desired height to be exactly the same as my `imageView`'s width and height.

Now, How can I get the width and height of any given `imageView`?
given that the `imageView` initially is empty, but just defined with `findViewById()`

Comment: Did you try `yourImageView.getHeight()` ? What does it return, 0?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680499/how-to-get-the-width-and-height-of-an-android-widget-imageview

Comment: yes, as the imageView initially is empty"has no image displayed" when i use getheight as a parameter to the method "bitmap.createsclaledbitmap" logcat says height should be greater than 0

Answer (score 0):

You must wait until the view is laid out to have dimensions. You can achieve this with a `ViewTreeObserver`:

```
final ImageView view = ...;
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener()
{
    @Override
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onGlobalLayout()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        else
            getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

        // width and height are available here.
    }
});
```

Another option is to have your own class derived from `ImageView` and override `onLayout()`