# Android Card UI : card resize (gabrielemariotti)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, android-cards, cardslib

I'm making an android app with cards UI, by using the library: https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib

I want to make a custom card which will be smaller than the default card size. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Just a heads up - [`CardView`](https://developer.android.com/preview/material/ui-widgets.html#cardview) is now the canonical Android card view.

Answer (score 2):

The default card has a min height.

You can override this value in your dimens.xml:

```
<dimen name="card_base_empty_height">96dp</dimen>
```

Comment: This will change the minHeight of all cards. How can I set the minHeight of only a specific card?

Comment: **Answer:** In my case, I used a [custom card-layout](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/CARD.md#use-your-custom-card-layout) as specified in the documentation. I changed `android:layout_height` to my desired value. However my initial intention was to change the height based on a `ImageView` in the custom card-layout. For this, I added `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`. Another solution would bet to get the `ImageView` height [programmaticaly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680499/how-to-get-the-width-and-height-of-an-android-widget-imageview).