# Image size for downloading from the server

Tags: android

I'm displaying some images from the RESTFul web service via `GridView`. Maximum rows number is 4. How to calculate optimal width of image depends on that that screen can be in portrait mode and in landscape mode? Or I should use some constants for that, depends on screen density?

Comment: Get the device screen width on pixels, then just make any calc you need to find the needed width, did you have any problems with this?

Answer (score 0):

PLay with the GridView attributes, specifically `android:numColumns="auto_fit" and android:stretchMode.` For example:

```
<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/myGrid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="60dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"    
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create/update the grid params on runtime, just before downloading the image.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680499/how-to-get-the-width-and-height-of-an-android-widget-imageview) post for getting the view's width/height on run-time.

BTW - I strongly recommend [ImageDownloader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to download and display image - it can use cache and save memory while loading scaled images.