# Adding Grid view in Group header and Grid view in Child view in Expandable listview in android

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistadapter

In my program I am trying to add both group header and Child view as Grid view in Expandable `listview` in android.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it with reference to following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680499/how-to-get-the-width-and-height-of-an-android-widget-imageview)

```
 int finalHeight, finalWidth;
final ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.scaled_image);
final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.size_label);
ViewTreeObserver vto = iv.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
public boolean onPreDraw() {
    iv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
    finalHeight = iv.getMeasuredHeight();
    finalWidth = iv.getMeasuredWidth();
    tv.setText("Height: " + finalHeight + " Width: " + finalWidth);
    return true;
 }
});
```