# When has the layout finished loading

Tags: android, layout, load, onresume, onstart

For my app I need to get the height and width of an image. However, the image has no params when I try to get them in the onCreate/ onStart/ onResume method. 
At which point can I get the values of the image/ has the image been loaded?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: try getting the width and height when the image is already viewable on your activity.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to achieve... but my method needs to be called immideately after the layout isVisible

Comment: then onResume is your best chance. otherwise, your image might be empty

Comment: You're right, the image is empty ahh... thank you :)

Comment: I have just found out that for both onStart and onResume, the layout is still completely empty (white) at the time of the image query. No wonder that the image is still empty at that time. Do you have any idea when the image has loaded and I can query the dimensions? :)

Comment: where do you get your image?

Comment: From the layout xml (ImageView)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ViewTreeObserver` with `ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener`.

For more details, check this answer: [How to get the width and height of an android.widget.ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680499/how-to-get-the-width-and-height-of-an-android-widget-imageview)