# Android layout confusing

Tags: android

Here is my capture picture:
[image]

And here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="left">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/messageIn"          
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:text="23:23"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_yellow"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:text="HIHIHIHIHIHI" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

However, if the text "HIHIHIHIHIHI" changes to "HIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHI":
the time will missing and the bubble will fill parent
[image]

How can I do so that the time will still to the right of the bubble even the text is mult-line?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="left">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="23:23"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_yellow"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/timeIn" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:text="HIHIHIHIHIHI" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

To work for small texts also (To resize the width of messageIn according to message) and time to appear right of message (not right aligned)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/wrapper"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="1.0" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lin_lay1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_yellow"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:text="HIHIHI" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lin_lay2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="23:23" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: work for long text , but for short text, the bubble will many blank area

Comment: not a solution, there will be a gap between the two text views

Comment: sorry, in your version, the time is the rightmost, but I want the time just right to the bubble

Comment: I tried searching for more information on setting weightSum lower that the actual sum of layout weight, but couldn`t find anything. Can you reference us/ elaborate on how/why this works? According to the Android documentation, I assumed weightSum should reset to the actual sum of layout weights, but then... it obviously doesn`t.

Comment: @ile Refer http://ugiagonzalez.com/2012/01/19/android-linearlayout-distribution-explained-weight-and-sizes/ to have a clear idea on weights and width

Answer (score 1):

Use android:maxwidth in your textview.

Comment: it is the only and best solution until you provide another one :)

Comment: It is the only solution so far, mine answer is like yours, only more exhaustful

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to set the android:maxWidth="" property of your "messageIn" TextView. On runtime - get the width of the device screen, the width of the "timeIn" TextView and set the difference (screen width - timeIn width) with setMaxWidth(int maxpixels) method of TextView.

[See how to get screen size here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/android-how-to-get-screen-dimensions)

[See how to get GUI object size here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649438/how-to-get-the-dimensions-of-a-drawable-in-an-imageview)

Comment: In runtime, I can get the timeIn textView? Since my timeIn is set in runtime

Comment: Sorry, I don`t think I understood the question. I meant you should do:
TextView messageIn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageIn);
TextView timeIn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeIn);
int timeInW = timeIn.getMeasuredHeight();

Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int screenWidth = size.x; 

messageIn.setMaxWidth(screenWidth - timeInW);

Comment: or if you`re developing for API<=13 replace the line with 
"int screenWidth = display.getWidth();"

Answer (score 0):

make use of layout_weight it will take only assigned space and will not cover time textview.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightsum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeIn"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:text="23:23"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageIn"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_yellow"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:text="HIHIHIHIHIHI" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is not really a solution, it will keep the width of both TextView fixed and jjLin seems to need a resizable TextView for the message

Comment: oh! then answer of user936414 is correct just try his answer.

Comment: okay then one thing can do it. make the textview(HIHIHIHIHI) in a linearlayout and give 0.7 weight to that linearlayout. it will fix the width of linearlayout and if textview in it will expand, can expand to the width of linearlayout in which it is.

Comment: No, it`s not correct - it leaves a gap between the two objects

Comment: then you should specify max width for Edittext. according to the width of time textview.

Comment: if you change your messageIn layout weight to 1 and removed timeIn layout weight - it would work, as in user936414`s answer. Or you can change the layout weightSum to 0.7 and remove the weight of messageIn

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways:-

1. You can use Linear Layout and set its  android:orientation="horizontal" and you need to fix the layout_width for a Textview.
2. Concatinate time with TextView in the code.

   ```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/wrapper"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/messageIn"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
    android:text="HIHIHIHIdsfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffHIHI" />
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/timeIn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="23:23"/>


    </LinearLayout>
   ```

Comment: you are not considering different screen sizes

Comment: the width of the TextView is fixed, so concatenation will not resize it