# setImageResource then getting width and height

Tags: java, android

I need to change the image in an imageview then get the width. Problem is, it gives me the width of the last image.

```
headpic.setImageResource(head[x]);
int width = headpic.getWidth();
```

if i then run this code again with x being the same value it gets the correct width.

Comment: headpic probably isn't updated yet when you use the .getWidth() method.

Comment: yea thats what i was thinking its not in onCreate() it in a method from a button.

Comment: You probably need the OnPreDraw event.
Check here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649438/how-to-get-the-dimensions-of-a-drawable-in-an-imageview/4649842

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming headpic is your imageview. If so, wouldn't `headpic.getWidth();` be getting the width of the imageview instead of the image?

You could get the drawable from the imageview and use `.getIntrinsicWidth();`

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you. int width = headpic.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();