# OnPreDraw() is getting called over and over. what could explain it?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

at least it is doing what I want it to do (centering my view at runtime) but why is it doing it over and over? my understanding is that it should be called when the view tree has something to draw, which should not be multiple times every second.  here I am logging its calls

[image: OnPreDraw() calls]

why does OnPreDraw() keeps getting called over and over even when nothing is happening on screen? is that terrible for performance? I only want it to be called when there is actually something to be drawn.

the view location_manager is part of the action bar, if it matters.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740447/why-is-onpredraw-called-twice

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the `OnPreDrawListener` in the first line of your `onPreDraw()` method if you only want it to get called once:

```
myView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
```

Comment: `vto` has to be declared as `final`

Comment: this is crashing my app immediately. did you mean myView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this); ?

Comment: @user3453281 Yeah, that is probably better since it's possible the old view tree observer is no longer alive.

Answer (score 4):

I found something interesting: `OneShotPreDrawListener`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/OneShotPreDrawListener

change this:

```
val viewTreeObserver = view.viewTreeObserver
    val onPreDrawListener = object : ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
        override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
            view.viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
            // do some thing
            return false
        }
    }
viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(onPreDrawListener)
```

to:

```
OneShotPreDrawListener.add(view) {
    // do some thing
}
```