# android bitmap/drawable size after imageview scaletype set to matrix

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, imageview, drawable

How can I get the size of the bitmap/drawable from the ImageView after its scale type has been set to matrix?

I have tried the following, but everything returns 0

```
Drawable drawable = imageview.getDrawable();
Rect bounds = drawable.getBounds();
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649438/how-to-get-the-dimensions-of-a-drawable-in-an-imageview/4649842#4649842

Comment: It doesnt have to do with it being set to matrix I think, it returns 0 because by the time thats called it hasnt been assigned a size yet, in the post Daniel linked the ViewTreeObserver part is key