# How to access size of Android Drawable

Tags: android, kotlin, drawable

I have the following drawable, called `small`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true"
    android:shape="oval"
    >

    <size
        android:height="10dp"
        android:width="10dp"
        />

    <solid android:color="#FF666666" />

</shape>
```

I would like to access the `height` and `width` defined in `size`. This is the line that gets the drawable:

```
val drawable: GradientDrawable = getDrawable(R.drawable.small) as GradientDrawable
```

`GradientDrawable` does not seem to have any accessors that provide the `size` and its fields. Even running in the debugger I see no fields that are set to `10dp`. Is there a way to access the `size` `height` and `width`?

Comment: Have you tried `getIntrinsicHeight()` and `getIntrinsicWidth()`?

Comment: This is the doc link that backs up comment from @CommonsWare: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable

Comment: @CommonsWare `getIntrinsicHeight` `getIntrinsicWidth` Doesn't return you actual size. For the case above its return 26 , 26 but actual size is 10dp. I'm not sure he may be have to get actual width and height from bitmap by setting up `BitmapFactory.Options()` for `densityDpi`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The suggestion of [@CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) in the comments is correct you have to use `getIntrinsicHeight()` and `getIntrinsicWidth()` to programmatically get the Drawable size but you have to convert those values from pixels to dps to access them in dp values.

**Example:**

```
val drawable: Drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.small) as Drawable
val heightDp = pxToDp(this, drawable.intrinsicHeight.toFloat())
val widthDp = pxToDp(this, drawable.intrinsicWidth.toFloat())
```

with the below helper function to convert the pixels to dps:

```
fun pxToDp(context: Context, px: Float): Float {
    return px / context.resources.displayMetrics.density
}
```

Based on your example above the `val heightDp` and the `val widthDp` both will have 10dp value.

Comment: thank you. this seems to work. there is something strange in that values in the xml are `10dp` but `pxToDp` returns `10.181818...`. i'm not sure where the decimal is coming in.

Comment: yes this is because the division of pixels with the device density returns a float where the pixels and density are variables from device to device so you have to get it to Int like pxToDp(this, drawable.intrinsicHeight.toFloat()).toInt()